# In Elasticsearch cluster, is there a way through which shards can be allocated a particular node during the time of creation?

Tags: elasticsearch, routes, kibana, sharding, opensearch

I have a multinode elasticsearch cluster. On that cluster, I want to divide shards of same index on different nodes.

Suppose a document is to be ingested into the index that have different key-value pairs. Based on that key-value, I want my master-node to allocate a `specific data-node` that contains a list of documents having the `same key-value`.

My approach is to have a single index across the nodes available in the cluster and the shards of this index should get distributed in such a manner that the document having similar key-value pair be on same node. Is there a way around to this?

Also I want to increase number of shards in an index but getting error, `"index <index_name> must be read-only to resize index."` How do I increase number of shards?

Comment: "index doctor" is not an Elasticsearch error, it's not clear where that is coming from but you should ask another question for it

Answer (score 1):

there is the [`_routing` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/mapping-routing-field.html) which can group documents in a particular shard. but you cannot automatically assign a shard with a value to a specific node. the closest you could get would be to manually handle it via [reroute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/cluster-reroute.html)

however why you would want to do that is not clear, and definitely not recommended as it's a lot of manual control over something that Elasticsearch is pretty good at handling

Comment: let say the data which is to be ingested has some value. Based on this value can we assign a particular shard available in an index?

Comment: not a specific shard, no. but you can group all documents with that value in one shard